# In common-lisp how can i override/change evaluation behaviour for a specific type of object?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval

In common-lisp, I want to implement a kind of reference system like this:

Suppose that I have:

`(defclass reference () ((host) (port) (file)))`

and also I have:

`(defun fetch-remote-value (reference) ...)` which fetches and deserializes a lisp object.

How could I intervene in the evaluation process so as whenever a reference object is being evaluated, the remote value gets fetched and re-evaluated again to produce the final result?

EDIT:

A more elaborate description of what I want to accomplish:

Using cl-store I serialize lisp objects and send them to a remote file(or db or anything) to be saved. Upon successful storage I keep the host,port and file in a reference object. I would like, whenever eval gets called on a reference object, to first retrieve the object, and then call eval on the retrieved value. Since a reference can be also serialized in other (parent) objects or aggregate types, I can get free recursive remote reference resolution by modyfing eval so i dont have to traverse and resolve the loaded object's child references myself.

EDIT:
Since objects always evaluate to themselves, my question is a bit wrongly posed. Essentially what I would like to do is:

I would like intercept the evaluation of symbols so that when their value is an object of type REFERENCE then instead of returning the object as the result of the symbol evaluation, to return the result of (fetch-remote-value object) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: you cannot do this, except by rewriting the function eval and modifying your Lisp's compiler. The rules of evaluation are fixed Lisp standard.

*Edit* After reading the augmented question, I don't think, that you can achieve full transperency for your references here. In a scenario like

```
(defclass foo () (reference :accessor ref))
(ref some-foo)
```

The result of the call to ref is simply a value; it will not be considered for evaluation regardless of its type.

Of course, you could define your accessors in a way, which does the resolution transparently:

```
(defmacro defresolver (name class slot)
    `(defmethod ,name ((inst ,class))
        (fetch-remote-reference (slot-value inst ',slot))))

(defresolver foo-reference foo reference)
```

*Edit* You can (sort of) hook into the symbol resolution mechanism of Common Lisp using symbol macros:

```
(defmacro let-with-resolution (bindings &body body) 
    `(symbol-macrolet ,(mapcar #'(lambda (form) (list (car form) `(fetch-aux ,(cadr form)))) bindings) ,@body))

(defmethod fetch-aux ((any t)) any)
(defmethod fetch-aux ((any reference)) (fetch-remote-reference any))
```

However, now things become pretty arcane; and the variables are no longer variables, but magic symbols, which merely look like variables. For example, modifying the content of a variable "bound" by this macro is not possible. The best you can do with this approach is to provide a `setf` expansion for `fetch-aux`, which modifies the original place.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the plain closures solutions?

Comment: I added a more elaborate description of the problem to the question

Comment: "The result of the call to ref is simply a value; it will not be considered for evaluation regardless of its type" : Of course, but if we could put it in the eval process then if someone binds that value to a var or implicitly calls it , it will be automatically fetched and resolved then by the evaluator. Anyway your proposals are very helpful, but I hoped for a way to inject the special handling of reference type in the vains of the evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

Although libraries for [lazy evaluatione](http://common-lisp.net/project/clazy/) and [object persistence](http://common-lisp.net/project/elephant/) bring you part of the way, Common Lisp does not provide a portable way to implement fully transparent persistent values. Lazy or persistent values still have to be explicitly [forced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

[MOP](http://www.alu.org/mop/index.html) can be used to implement lazy or persistent objects though, with the slot values transparently forced. It would take a change in the internals of the Common Lisp implementations to provide general transparency, so you could do e.g. `(+ p 5)` with `p` potentially holding a persistent or lazy value.

Comment: I would like to look at it at a more abstract way: In (+ p 5) , p could be a reference to something arbitrary so that its value could be anything from a value in a memory address or a resource fetched by a scheme. Lazy or eager is orthogonal to where the value of the reference or expression resides. Lazy or eager defines WHEN to fetch the value of an expression or reference. I want to be able to control FROM WHERE the value of the expression will be fetched, either by specializing in some way the evaluation of expressions on the reference type, or intercepting their result.

Comment: I know the language doesnt provide the possibility of fully transparent persistent values. I just wanted to know: 1.How difficult would be to change an implementation so that it supports fully transparent and decoupled persistence of values. 2.Would it be worth? I mean would any benefit from such a thing to an extent that would justify the attempt?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly change the evaluation mechanisms. You would need to write a compiler for your code to something else. Kind of an embedded language.

On the CLOS level there are several ways to deal with it:

Two examples:

- write functions that dispatch on the reference object:

  (defmethod move ((object reference) position)
     (move (dereference reference) position))

  (defmethod move ((object automobile) position)
     ...))

This gets ugly and might be automated with a macro.

- [CHANGE-CLASS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_chg_cl.htm)

CLOS objects already have an indirection, because they can change their class. Even though they may change their class, they keep their identity. CHANGE-CLASS is destructively modifying the instance.

So that would make it possible to pass around reference objects and at some point load the data, change the reference object to some other class and set the slots accordingly. This changing the class needs to be triggered somewhere in the code.

One way to have it automagically triggered might be an error handler that catches some kinds of errors involving reference object.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a layer on top of your deserialize mechanism that dispatches based on the type of the incoming data.